# can't link to external javascript in html

Tags: javascript, html

It IS a very trivial question, but I just can't solve it, no matter what I try or how I search. I'm trying to build a page hosted in my University's servers and I can't link external javascript files. Internal javascript works fine, so I don't think that is a problem with the servers' configuration, but with my files. Here are the codes:

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
    <script  type="text/javascript" src="game.js"></script>
    <title>First Web Game</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="Ptest">oi</p>        
</body>
</html>
```

game.js:

```
document.getElementById("Ptest").innerHTML="test";
```

P.S.: the CSS works fine!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The script is above `<p id="Ptest">`, so the paragraph doesn't exist when you try to get it by its id.

Move the script to after the paragraph or wrap the script in a function and call that function after the paragraph exists (e.g. from a `load` event handler).

Comment: Nervermind, it did work

Comment: Yeah. It "works," but inline Javascript is a no-no.

Comment: @DissidentRage — There isn't any inline JS here

Comment: Then use the second of the two options I presented.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into [Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event). Put the following into your game.js file (and keep the script tag in the head).

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>Game Test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="game.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="ptest"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

**game.js**

```
function init() {
    document.getElementById('ptest').innerHTML = 'loaded';
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',init,false);
```

Comment: What browser are you using? It should say "loaded" in the page.

Comment: Nevermind, it was already solved by the answer I chose. Thank you.

Comment: "Solved." Until people start complaining that the game takes too long just to display the loading page, or until you realize you can't manipulate the DOM correctly because it's not completely loaded when the script is read.

Comment: So I should use the other solution, the one with events? My browser is Google Chrome.

Comment: I honestly have no idea why it wouldn't work in Chrome. I just copied and pasted it. The page contents say 'loaded' on mine.